# vuejs unable to hide side menu bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, vue.js

I am trying to hide side menu bar except for the hamburger icon when "expanded". I tried removing some parts of the css but am still unable to hide the little side menu bar.

The links are the images is the results of the menu:
[pre-expand-menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b77hV.png)
[expanded-menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOwtB.png)

templates:

```
<div class="menu" :class="{ 'small-menu': smallMenu }">
<MenuItem
  v-for="(item, index) in menuTree"
  :key="index"
  :data="item.children"
  :label="item.label"
  :depth="0"
  :smallMenu="smallMenu"
/>
<i @click="smallMenu = !smallMenu" class="material-icons">menu</i>
</div>
```

styles:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.menu {
  background: grey;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 240px;
  left: 110;
  top: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #ececec;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
  i {
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    font-size: 20px;
    top: 15px;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  &.small-menu {
    overflow: inherit;
    width: 60px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    i {
      left: 20px;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Would you please try to provide an interactive code sample by adding a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)? You can add Vue JS in your version to it.

Comment: This is not immediately concerning your issue at hand, but please consider rendering your code more accessible for users with disabilities, or even just to those who prefer keyboards. If you use a `click` binding on a non-interactive event, you will need `tabindex="0"` and `@keydown` as well. And for toggling a menu open and close, [please check out the Disclosure pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/disclosure/) for some idea of how to mark it up correctly.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, did you try to console log the value of smallMenu variable to see if it actually changes on a click ?

Comment: This should really be a comment on the original post